# Formatting a character column as numeric with less than and greater than symbols

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a set of data with laboratory submitted calculations of microbiological log reductions.  Sometimes it is only possible to state a value of greater than or less than a certain figure.  Example data here:

```
test.df <- tribble(
~x, ~y, ~z,
#--|--|----
"pa", "lab1", "-3.52",
"pa", "lab2", ">5.0",
"pa", "lab3", "<-1.567")
```

Are there any routines which would allow me to format this with correct alignment, i.e.,

```
Organism     Laboratory     LogReduction
--------     ----------     ------------
pa           lab1            -3.52
pa           lab2           > 5.0
pa           lab3           <-1.567
```

I.e., decimal points line up, and all greater-than or less-than symbols line up as well ?

Basically, I'm trying to end up with a dataframe like this which I can print with kable

```
test.df <- tribble(
~x, ~y, ~z,
#--|--|----
"pa", "lab1", " -3.52 ",
"pa", "lab2", "> 5.0  ",
"pa", "lab3", "<-1.567")
```

I've tried some sprintf mangling but can't see anything that fits the bill.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen a function to do that, but you should be able to write one.  For example:

```
prefix <- gsub("[^><]*", "", test.df$z)
prefix[nchar(prefix) < 1] <- " "
suffix <- gsub("[<>]", "", test.df$z)
suffix <- format(as.numeric(suffix))
test.df$z <- paste0(prefix, suffix)
```

At this point, `test.df$z` has the format you want, but when you put it in a Markdown table, the leading whitespace will be deleted and things won't line up.  To fix that, you can try replacing the space characters with numeric space characters.  You also need to replace "-" with a minus sign instead of a hyphen.

This works for me in HTML:

```
test.df$z <- gsub(" ", "&numsp;", test.df$z)
test.df$z <- gsub("-", "&minus;", test.df$z)
kable(test.df)
```

It produces this table:

[image: screenshot]

If you're using some other output format besides HTML, the space and hyphen substitutions would have to be different.